# submit form input data as form file

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a textarea element containing a large amount of data.  On submit the server returns a too large error.

While I cannot post textareas with large amounts of data, I can submit large files using a form.

I would like to capture the form's textarea data in a submit event (easy to do) and repackage it as a file to get around the post
data limit.

Can this be done?

Update:  Let me focus the question.  Forget why I want to do it.  Question is now simply; Can input data (input text, textarea, ...) from a form be repackaged as a file type and posted from the client browser as file?

AND recall that I can send huge amounts of data as a file type, just not other input types.  File types = sky's the limit.  Other form types are limited to exactly 1MB.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: It's a 413.  Note I've updated the question.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: Not likely, as the post handler still hits the server somehow. And you can write to the file system via JS. You're still going to run into limitations when converting input into a file.

Comment: So, at the client, form data that is collected in cannot be changed into a file?  Remember, I have no problem sending huge files back in the post, just huge 'other' things.  I suppose I'd also have to remove the textarea element itself before I serialized.  I can't understand why limits would be different for files verses input data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from requinix at forums.phpfreaks.com

```
    var text_area_data = jQuery('#id_textarea').val();
    var blob = new Blob ([text_area_data], { type: "text/plain" });

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("textarea", blob);

    jQuery.ajax({
       url      : 'ajax_textarea_save.php',
       method   : 'POST',
       data     : fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false
    });
```

Data shows up at server in a file with parameters in the $_FILES array.

Answer (score 0):

What data type(object) are you using for storing? Using a longtext instead of text will allow you to store a large data objects that can be as large as 4 GB (expressed as 2^32 -1) and store up to 4,294,967,295 characters with 4 bytes of overhead storage,

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Please note I've updated the question.  I failed to make it clear this is not a database question.  It concerns the posting of the data back to the server.  The apache server issues the error.